# convert static html cod to dynamic code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Please how could I convert the flowing static code to dynamic in wordpress..I've been trying for a Week.I need 6 itemes of stories .thanks alot.

```
<div class="news_culome">

  <div class="stories">

      <h3>
        <a href="#">إعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحت
        إعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحت
        <img src="images/story_img.jpg" alt="story image" width="220px" height="150px">           </a>
      </h3>
      <p>إعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحت إعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحت إعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه الرسالة جرى تحتإعداد هذه </p>
      <span class="meta">
        9:00am  || 10/10/2015
      </span>
      <span><a href="#">المزيد</a></span> 
    </div>


  </div><!-- news_culome -->
```

Comment: Go and study the bundled themes. Great place to start

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include this in a post. Create a new post and paste the code in the text tab rather than the visual tab. Follow the same method if you want to place it in a page.

Further clarification would be great.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the code to be added on to any particular page, in your wp-admin:
- Go to Appearance > Editor.
- Locate the page you want to edit from the list on the right.
- modify/add the code in the page.
- Click "Update file" at the bottom of the page.
- Done.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Never ever use the back end editor. One small mistake and you break your site